# Getting TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out. on AWS while using scrapy?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-crawler, scrapy

This is my scrapy code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
import pymongo
import time

class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    rating = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    category = scrapy.Field()
    source = scrapy.Field()
    user_info = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
    mobile_no = scrapy.Field()
    url_1 = scrapy.Field()
    model_name = scrapy.Field()

class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "flipkart_reviews"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
    urls = []
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
    db = connection.electronics
    db_coll = db.flipkart_url
    d = []




    start_urls = ['http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/product-reviews/ITMEYFHGFDB75R73?pid=MOBEYAW2RFHQG83F&type=top']#urls

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        sites = response.css('div.review-list div[review-id]')
        items = []

        model_name = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').re(r'Reviews of (.*?)$')[0].strip().encode('ascii','ignore')
        for site in sites:
                item = CompItem()
                item['email'] = None
                item['mobile_no'] = int(0)
                item['category'] = None
                item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"line fk-font-normal bmargin5 dark-gray")]/strong/text()').extract()[0].encode('ascii','ignore')
                item['date'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
                item['model_name'] = model_name
                item['text'] = site.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"review-text")]/text()').extract()[0]
                item['rating'] = float(site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"fk-stars")]/@title').extract()[0].split("stars")[0])
                item['name'] = ''.join(site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]//text()').extract()).strip()
                item["url"] = response.url
                item['source'] = int(3)
                yield item
```

This works fine on the local machine without any errors .But moment I put it on AWS it starts throwing me error.

```
2015-10-05 12:08:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:09:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:09:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/product-reviews/ITMEYFHGFDB75R73?pid=MOBEYAW2RFHQG83F&type=top> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
2015-10-05 12:10:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:11:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:11:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/product-reviews/ITMEYFHGFDB75R73?pid=MOBEYAW2RFHQG83F&type=top> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
2015-10-05 12:12:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:13:26 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-10-05 12:13:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/product-reviews/ITMEYFHGFDB75R73?pid=MOBEYAW2RFHQG83F&type=top> (failed 3 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
2015-10-05 12:13:48 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-4/product-reviews/ITMEYFHGFDB75R73?pid=MOBEYAW2RFHQG83F&type=top>: TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
2015-10-05 12:13:48 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-10-05 12:13:48 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 3,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 3,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 1119,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 5, 6, 43, 48, 727700),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 13,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 5, 6, 37, 26, 877249)}
2015-10-05 12:13:48 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Earlier the script was working very well.I have tried various methods - 
1. Putting up `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`
2. Googled the same problem and read about  Web scraping etiquette.

But everything in vain.

Comment: What happens when you use curl to download the page from AWS?

Comment: like `curl "url"` ???

Comment: yes. Basically can you actually access the webpage from your box or not? i.e. is the problem with the code or with the machine?

Comment: [22] 31217 I get this as output

Comment: You should see the webpage in the console if curl is able to access the site: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/curl-examples/ If you are not able to access the site via curl it would suggest that there is a problem with the connection to the site. Can you verify that you can connect to the webpage some other way perhaps? can you show the error that you get as well please?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.flipkart.com port 80: Connection timed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91362/discussion-between-john-dene-and-niallhaslam).

Answer (score 5):

There are few checks that you can.

- Try opening the same url in the using requests module or urllib.
- try doing "wget" of the page.

if above steps yields result it means we are getting response and there is problem with Our Spider way of requesting. Few things we can do w.r.t to Spider now.

1. Increase the DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT in the settings file.
2. Increase RETRY_TIMES = 10
3. Increase the DOWNLOAD_DELAY
4. This is the last resort. Chances are there that website has reorganized that we are bot and trying to get away with us. In this case we need to proxy. Use this middleware [https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies Scrapy Proxy Middleware][1]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ip is blocked by the website